"go mod why" is not always working. How to identify dependency origin in such a cases?
By running go mod tidy I'm ending up with a list of required dependencies and some of those are getting reported by security tools as vulnerable.
What's the best way to identify why dependency is there is case you get such a response after running go mod why?
(main module does not need package <package_name>)

As question title mentions, I'm looking for a workaround. I'm aware that this is reported bug, but it's 6 years old, and unlikely to be fixed soon.
Here is just one example of go mod graph. It's showing golang.org/x/net module as a root dependency but it's never directly referenced anywhere in the code:
go mod graph | deptree -d 3

dev.azure.com/company/modules/_git/testproto.git (go1.22)
 ├── golang.org/x/net@v0.25.0 (go1.18) => [v0.28.0]
 │    ├── golang.org/x/crypto@v0.23.0 => [v0.26.0]
 │    ├── golang.org/x/sys@v0.20.0 (go1.18) => [v0.24.0]
 │    ├── golang.org/x/term@v0.20.0 => [v0.23.0]
 │    └── golang.org/x/text@v0.15.0 (go1.18) => [v0.17.0]
 ├── golang.org/x/sys@v0.20.0 (go1.18) => [v0.24.0]


Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Try the -m flag. From the advice later in the linked GitHub issue, if that still shows nothing it's a bug.
go mod why -m deptree

An example from a project I'm working on without -m:
go mod why github.com/golang/protobuf

# github.com/golang/protobuf
(main module does not need package github.com/golang/protobuf)

and with:
go mod why -m github.com/golang/protobuf

# github.com/golang/protobuf
github.com/willbeason/wikipedia/cmd/normalize-wikipedia
github.com/dgraph-io/badger/v3
github.com/golang/protobuf/proto

The official documentation from go help mod why gives an explanation of this behavior, but I don't understand it.

If the -m flag is given, why treats the
arguments as a list of modules and finds a path to any package in each
of the modules.

